# XCTest on Xcode 8 GM Seed

Tags: ios, xctest, ios10, xcode8, xctestcase

I have a set of XCTest automation scripts running UI test of my app, and I am trying out on Xcode 8 for iOS 10 testing.

However, seems like the XCTest framework is running very slower than Xcode 7 at the moment.  Is it only me experiencing this issue?

Or is it my app's problem; the way it was built or XCTest is written?

Anyone else experience the same issue of slowness on Xcode 8?

Thanks,

Comment: Everything I do with the seed version is crawling!

Comment: It works fine for me! is it for swift 2.3 or swift 3.0?

Comment: Are you running on a device or simulator?

Comment: I have also been having this issue and now am getting a failure on a test because it fails to find an element in the 15 second window for interactions

Comment: I am experiencing the same slowness in Xcode 8 UI tests. Runs as expected in Xcode 7. Runs crazy slow in Xcode 8.